# Store the result of many for loops

Tags: c, arrays, list, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a code in python and now I am struggling to write it in c (to optimize the speed) because I've never used c!

Previously I used to store the resulted data in a dictionary or in a list of arrays but I don't know what is the suitable structure and how to store it here in c.

I read the data from a file called (attempt) then I process it using the functions written in the code. Three `for loops` are used to produce the required data but I don't know how to store it!

the code which contains the loops

```
for (i=0; i<m; i++){
   igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
   igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
   igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);
   for (j=0; j < igraph_vector_size(&v2); j++) {
     for (k=0; k < igraph_vector_size(&v1); k++) {
       printf("%li %d %f %d %f\n", i, from, VECTOR(v1)[k] ,to, VECTOR(v2)[j]);     
     } 
   }
}     

 //EDIT: concerning the different data types, at the end all elements inside the loops could have have the same type so


int n1, n2;
for (i=0; i<m; i++){
    igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
    igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
    igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);
    for (j=0; j < igraph_vector_size(&v2); j++) {
      for (k=0; k < igraph_vector_size(&v1); k++) {
        n1 =  floor(VECTOR(v1)[k]);
        n2 =  floor(VECTOR(v2)[j]);
        printf("%li %d %d %d %d\n", i, from, n1 ,to, n2);                        
      }
    }
 }
```

The result is on the form

```
0 1 2.000000 2 1.000000
0 1 2.000000 2 3.000000
0 1 2.000000 2 4.000000
1 2 1.000000 3 2.000000
1 2 3.000000 3 2.000000
1 2 4.000000 3 2.000000
          .
          .
          .
```

Instead of printing this data, I would like to store it as

```
data = [ [ [1, 2.000000, 2 ,1.000000], [1, 2.000000, 2, 3.000000], [1, 2.000000, 2, 4.000000] ], [  [2, 1.000000, 3, 2.000000], [2, 3.000000, 3, 2.000000], ...  ], ... ]
```

Then if I need to access the data

1. for index 0, `data[0]= [ [1, 2.000000, 2 1.000000], [1, 2.000000, 2, 3.000000], [1, 2.000000, 2, 4.000000] ]`
2. and `data[0][2]=[1 2.000000 2 4.000000]`
3. and <s>`data[0][2][3]= [4.000000]`</s> `data[0][2][3]= 4.000000`

Is this possible in my case? I would be very very grateful for any help.

P.S: I will be very happy to explain anything not clear.

**ADDITION**

Here is the full code (if needed)

```
#include <igraph/igraph.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define sigma 1

void print_vector(igraph_vector_t *v, FILE *file) {
     long int i;
     for (i=0; i < igraph_vector_size(v); i++) {
        fprintf(file, "%li \n", (long int) VECTOR(*v)[i]);
     }
     fprintf(file,"\n");
 }


float rbf(int a, int b);

float rbf(int a, int b) {
  double inverse;
  double exp(double x;);
  double x;
  double result;

  inverse = ( 1/(sigma*sigma) );
  x = (- inverse * ( (a - b)*(a - b) ) );
  result = exp(x);
  return (result); 
} 

int main(void)
{

     igraph_t graph; 
     igraph_bool_t false;
     igraph_bool_t connected1, connected2, connected3, connected4, connected5, connected6;
     int ret;
     float rhs1;
     float rhs2;
     igraph_vector_t v1, v2;
     long int i, j, k, n, m ;
     igraph_integer_t from, to;
     igraph_adjlist_t adjlist;
     FILE *file;
     file = fopen("attempt", "r");
     if(!file){
        return 1;
     }

     igraph_read_graph_edgelist(&graph, file, 
                                0, false);

     fclose(file);

     igraph_vector_init(&v1, (igraph_vcount(&graph)) );
     igraph_vector_init(&v2, (igraph_vcount(&graph)) );
     igraph_adjlist_init(&graph, &adjlist, IGRAPH_ALL);

     n = igraph_vcount(&graph);
     m = igraph_ecount(&graph);
     for (i=0; i<m; i++){
        igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
        igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
        igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);
        for (j=0; j < igraph_vector_size(&v2); j++) {
          for (k=0; k < igraph_vector_size(&v1); k++) {
            printf("%li %d %f %d %f\n", i, from, VECTOR(v1)[k] ,to, VECTOR(v2)[j]);                        
          }
        }
     }

     //igraph_destroy(&graph);
}
```

and the file attempt contains this trial data

```
1 2
2 3
2 4
3 4
4 5
```

Comment: Semi-related, if you only care about improving speed (and not learning C) you might consider NumPy or Cython first

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks but I already wrote wrote it code in c, just I need now to store the results!

Comment: Based on your expected result you should go with creating a `struct` to hold the values you want to store and then make an array of that `struct` that you fill in the loop

Comment: @Noah16 I put an answer allowing to save the datas then for instance to print them after without supposing `igraph_vector_size()` always return the same value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would like to store it

you need a struct for each element, like

```
typedef Struct Data {
  int from;
  float vfrom;
  int to;
  float vto;
} Data;
```

Then an `Data**`.

Note doing that does not allow to have `data[0][2][3]= [4.000000]` else it is needed to have a `float ***` and this is not practical, it is `data[0][2].vto == 4.000000`

For instance replace

```
 for (i=0; i<m; i++){
    igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
    igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
    igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);
    for (j=0; j < igraph_vector_size(&v2); j++) {
      for (k=0; k < igraph_vector_size(&v1); k++) {
        printf("%li %d %f %d %f\n", i, from, VECTOR(v1)[k] ,to, VECTOR(v2)[j]);                        
      }
    }
 }
```

by

```
 Data ** all = malloc(m * sizeof(Data*));

 for (i=0; i<m; i++){
    igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
    igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
    igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);
    all[i] = malloc(igraph_vector_size(&v2)*graph_vector_size(&v1)*sizeof(Data));

    int idx = 0;

    for (j=0; j < igraph_vector_size(&v2); j++) {
      for (k=0; k < igraph_vector_size(&v1); k++) {
        all[i][idx].from = from;
        all[i][idx].vfrom = VECTOR(v1)[k];
        all[i][idx].to = to;
        all[i][idx].vto = VECTOR(v2)[j];
        idx += 1;
      }
    }
 }
```

Note it will be difficult to use the `Data**` after in case the number of entries in all the sub arrays is not known and the same, may be you need to save that numbers, for that :

```
typedef Struct Data {
  int from;
  float vfrom;
  int to;
  float vto;
} Data;

typedef Datas {
   int n;
   Data * datas;
} Datas;
```

allowing to do:

```
 Datas * all = malloc(m * sizeof(Datas));

 for (i=0; i<m; i++){
    igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
    igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
    igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);

    int jsup = igraph_vector_size(&v2);
    int ksup = igraph_vector_size(&v1);
    Data * a = malloc(jsup * ksup * sizeof(Data));

    all[i].n = jsup * ksup;
    all[i].datas = a;

    for (j=0; j < jsup; j++) {
      for (k=0; k < ksup; k++) {
        a->from = from;
        a->vfrom = VECTOR(v1)[k];
        a->to = to;
        a->vto = VECTOR(v2)[j];
        a += 1;
      }
    }
 }
```

then

```
printf("data : [");

for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
  Data * a = all[i].datas;

  printf(" [");

  for (int j = 0; j != all[i].n; ++j)
    printf(" [%d %f %d %f]", a[j].from, a[j].vfrom, a[j].to, a[j].vto);

  printf(" ]");
}

puts(" ]");
```

---

Here the full program :

```
#include <igraph/igraph.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define sigma 1

void print_vector(igraph_vector_t *v, FILE *file) {
     long int i;
     for (i=0; i < igraph_vector_size(v); i++) {
        fprintf(file, "%li \n", (long int) VECTOR(*v)[i]);
     }
     fprintf(file,"\n");
 }


float rbf(int a, int b);

float rbf(int a, int b) {
  double inverse;
  double exp(double x;);
  double x;
  double result;

  inverse = ( 1/(sigma*sigma) );
  x = (- inverse * ( (a - b)*(a - b) ) );
  result = exp(x);
  return (result); 
} 

typedef struct Data {
  int from;
  float vfrom;
  int to;
  float vto;
} Data;

typedef struct Datas {
   int n;
   Data * datas;
} Datas;


int main(void)
{

     igraph_t graph; 
     igraph_bool_t false;
     igraph_bool_t connected1, connected2, connected3, connected4, connected5, connected6;
     int ret;
     float rhs1;
     float rhs2;
     igraph_vector_t v1, v2;
     long int i, j, k, n, m ;
     igraph_integer_t from, to;
     igraph_adjlist_t adjlist;
     FILE *file;
     file = fopen("attempt", "r");
     if(!file){
        return 1;
     }

     igraph_read_graph_edgelist(&graph, file, 
                                0, false);

     fclose(file);

     igraph_vector_init(&v1, (igraph_vcount(&graph)) );
     igraph_vector_init(&v2, (igraph_vcount(&graph)) );
     igraph_adjlist_init(&graph, &adjlist, IGRAPH_ALL);

     n = igraph_vcount(&graph);
     m = igraph_ecount(&graph);
     Datas * all = malloc(m * sizeof(Datas));

     for (i=0; i<m; i++){
       igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
       igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
       igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);

       int jsup = igraph_vector_size(&v2);
       int ksup = igraph_vector_size(&v1);
       Data * a = malloc(jsup * ksup * sizeof(Data));

       all[i].n = jsup * ksup;
       all[i].datas = a;

       for (j=0; j < jsup; j++) {
         for (k=0; k < ksup; k++) {
           a->from = from;
           a->vfrom = VECTOR(v1)[k];
           a->to = to;
           a->vto = VECTOR(v2)[j];
           printf("%d %f %d %f\n", a->from, a->vfrom, a->to, a->vto);
           a += 1;
         }
       }
     }

     printf("data : [");

     for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
       Data * a = all[i].datas;

       printf(" [");

       for (int j = 0; j != all[i].n; ++j)
         printf(" [%d %f %d %f]", a[j].from, a[j].vfrom, a[j].to, a[j].vto);

       printf(" ]");
     }

     puts(" ]");

     /* free resources */
     igraph_destroy(&graph);
     igraph_vector_destroy(&v1);
     igraph_vector_destroy(&v2);
     igraph_adjlist_destroy(&adjlist);

     for (i=0; i<m; i++)
       free(all[i].datas);
     free(all);         

     return 0;
}
```

with the file *attempt* containing

```
1 2
2 3
2 4
3 4
4 5
```

execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1 2.000000 2 1.000000
1 2.000000 2 3.000000
1 2.000000 2 4.000000
2 1.000000 3 2.000000
2 3.000000 3 2.000000
2 4.000000 3 2.000000
2 1.000000 3 4.000000
2 3.000000 3 4.000000
2 4.000000 3 4.000000
2 1.000000 4 2.000000
2 3.000000 4 2.000000
2 4.000000 4 2.000000
2 1.000000 4 3.000000
2 3.000000 4 3.000000
2 4.000000 4 3.000000
2 1.000000 4 5.000000
2 3.000000 4 5.000000
2 4.000000 4 5.000000
3 2.000000 4 2.000000
3 4.000000 4 2.000000
3 2.000000 4 3.000000
3 4.000000 4 3.000000
3 2.000000 4 5.000000
3 4.000000 4 5.000000
4 2.000000 5 4.000000
4 3.000000 5 4.000000
4 5.000000 5 4.000000
data : [ [ [1 2.000000 2 1.000000] [1 2.000000 2 3.000000] [1 2.000000 2 4.000000] ] [ [2 1.000000 3 2.000000] [2 3.000000 3 2.000000] [2 4.000000 3 2.000000] [2 1.000000 3 4.000000] [2 3.000000 3 4.000000] [2 4.000000 3 4.000000] ] [ [2 1.000000 4 2.000000] [2 3.000000 4 2.000000] [2 4.000000 4 2.000000] [2 1.000000 4 3.000000] [2 3.000000 4 3.000000] [2 4.000000 4 3.000000] [2 1.000000 4 5.000000] [2 3.000000 4 5.000000] [2 4.000000 4 5.000000] ] [ [3 2.000000 4 2.000000] [3 4.000000 4 2.000000] [3 2.000000 4 3.000000] [3 4.000000 4 3.000000] [3 2.000000 4 5.000000] [3 4.000000 4 5.000000] ] [ [4 2.000000 5 4.000000] [4 3.000000 5 4.000000] [4 5.000000 5 4.000000] ] ]
```

Comment: Names more descriptive than `Data` and `Datas` (which is extra strange as a plural of an already plural term) would help. How about `Edge` and `Edges`? Also, it'd be good to explain that the reason a struct is needed is that in C, an array can only store one type of value -- you can't have an array that contains both ints and  floats.

Comment: @Caleb I use _Data_ and _Datas_ for the simple reason I do not know the semantic of these information so I am not able to give better names, the OP is able to rename them, this is just a detail. _Datas_ is a vector of _Data_, with size and value. About the second part of your remark I am also surprised because I said it is better to have the _struct_ rather than just `floats ***` ;-)

Comment: @bruno Thanks for this cooperation. I am in need to call the element in this way data[0][2][3]= [4.000000] because after once I will access the list of arrays to make a comparison with each element like: if (data[i][x][y]== j ) { ....}

Comment: @Noah16 I written all without any compilation nor execution, I do not have _igraph_ nor your input file. About `data[0][2][3]= [4.000000]` you probably mean 4.0 only rather than again an array, and to do that supposes you only have a three dimensional array of float rather than a double dimensional array of struct, do you **really** want to have that ?

Comment: @bruno Ya  you are right in this way data[0][2][3]= 4.0. But the printed data is so strange with a strange values and sizes in addition to a segmentation fault at the end :)

Comment: @Noah16 how to install igraph ? I have to get from https://github.com/igraph ? Your file _attempt_ contains _1 2 2 3 2 4 3 4 4_ ?

Comment: Yes exactly or from [here](https://igraph.org/c/) and the file contains these values (1 2 2 3 2 4 3 4 4 5) sorted in 5 lines where in each line there are 2 values separated by a space

Comment: @bruno Python doesn't have C-style arrays, but it's list type can store different types, so the OP is likely unaware that in C arrays are restricted to a single type.

Comment: @Caleb it is possible to use [classes](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/tutorial/classes.html) in Python, Python does not force to use an array to aggregate values

Comment: @Noah16 I just had a typo in the loop to print, I reused the variable _i_ by error, I corrected and added the full program and execution

Comment: @bruno Many thanks for this great help, it is working perfectly. Just a last question, why in the printing step you used (j != all[i].n) in last loop? why not (j < all[i].n;)? I didn't get it

Comment: @Noah16 you can do `<` if you prefer, but while _n_ is an non negative number and starting from 0 the behavior is the same

Comment: @bruno thanks again. As I saw it is neseccary in c to free the array and structure after using them. For the structure you constructed, I did: free(Data); then free(Datas); but it keeps giving me an error. Do I miss something in your work?

Comment: @Noah16 after looking at _igraph_ documentation (I do not know at all that lib)  I edited my answer to free the resources, look at the new definition of _main_ calling igraph destroy functions and necessary _free_ at the end